# how to convert std::string to boost::chrono::nanoseconds

Tags: c++, c++11, boost

I have tried lexical casting it from std::string and from long long. both gives zero value. any ideas?

```
boost::lexical_cast<boost::chrono::nanoseconds>(value) //value can be of std::string or long long type
```

Comment: How your string is formatted ?

Comment: What does the string contain?

Comment: Hi, what was your input?

Comment: @Jarod42 , @Galik , @Stefan :  for long `86808525850` .same goes for string as I used std::stoll() to convert from string to long long

Comment: [Edit] your question to contain __all__ relevant information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using lexical cast to a string first to see what is expected:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "boost/lexical_cast.hpp"
#include "boost/chrono.hpp"

int main()
{
    boost::chrono::nanoseconds test1{1000}; // could use long long here directly
    auto text = boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(test1);
    std::cout << text << '\n';
    auto val = boost::lexical_cast<boost::chrono::nanoseconds>(text);
    std::cout << val << '\n';
}
```

Prints:

```
1000 nanoseconds
1000 nanoseconds
```

Answer (score 1):

The time units do not have input/output streaming defined.

Just convert to ull first:

```
boost::chrono::nanoseconds(boost::lexical_cast<uint64_t>(value))
```